# google chrome https error

Tags: google-chrome, https

my site getting the problem while typing https:www.mysite.com/

showing red cross mark in the url head and  i didnt find the problem .can any one help .

in chrome help they given

"Your connection to the site is encrypted, but Google Chrome has detected mixed scripting on the page. Be careful if you’re entering personal information on this page. Mixed scripting can provide a loophole for someone to take over the page. This content could be third-party scripts or videos embedded on the page.

If you’re connected to the Internet via a public wireless network, mixed scripting is especially risky because wireless networks are easier to tamper with than wired networks."

please help me

Answer (score 2):

This error generally means that the site itself is being loaded over HTTPS, but that it's loading resources (scripts, style, images, etc) via HTTP. This is usually the result of hard-coding absolute URLs like:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/path/to/resource.js"></script>
```

Changing references like that use HTTPS:

```
<script src="https://mysite.com/path/to/resource.js"></script>
             ----^----
```

should solve the problem.